# adding "//= require bootstrap" leads to errors in nav-pills links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a perfectly working nav-pills menu for my rails app:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(articles_path) %>"><%= link_to "articles", articles_path, data: { toggle: "pill"} %></li>
      <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(appointments_path) %>"><%= link_to "appointments", appointments_path, data: { toggle: "pill"} %></li>
      <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(users_path) %>"><%= link_to "users", users_path, data: { toggle: "pill" } %></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then I added a dropdown menu somewhere else. Therefor I needed to add "//= require bootstrap" to application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The dropdown menu is working fine, but since I added "require bootstrap" the links in the nav-pills menu are not working anymore. When i click on a pill nothing happens and firefox shows for example this error in the console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /appointments

If I remove "require bootstraps" the links in the nav-pills menu work again but the dropdown menu doesn't drop down.

Any suggestions what I have to change in the nav-pills menu when I use "require bootstraps" in application.js?

Further information

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.4'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.6'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',    '3.3.6' # needed for bootstrap css
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',      '8.2.2'
  gem 'web-console', '3.1.1'
  gem 'spring',      '1.6.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.1.8'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard', '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3'
  gem 'puma',           '3.2.0'
end
```

application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "/*";
@import "/**/*";
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'articles' => 'administration#articles'
  get 'appointments' => 'administration#appointments'
  get 'createarticle' => 'articles#new'
  get 'createappointment' => 'appointments#new'
  get 'interface' => 'administration#interface'
  get 'help' => 'administration#help'
  get 'createuser' => 'users#new'
  get 'users' => 'administration#users'
  get    'adminlogin'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'adminlogin'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'adminlogout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :articles
  resources :appointments
end
```

Full error stack trace:

```
Sizzle</Sizzle.error() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:1503
Sizzle</Sizzle.tokenize() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:2160
Sizzle</Sizzle.select() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:2581
Sizzle() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:904
.find() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:2827
jQuery.fn.init() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:2950
jQuery() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:76
Tab.prototype.show() bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js:2097
Plugin/<() bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js:2170
.each() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:371
jQuery.prototype.each() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:138
Plugin() bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js:2165
clickHandler() bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js:2194
jQuery.event.dispatch() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:5226
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle() jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:487
```

Comment: can you add more information like the gem you used etc

Comment: From the error message, I'm guessing you've made an error in your current_page? Method. Can you get me that too? And btw, hope you've added the includes for sprockets and bootstrap in your application.scss

Comment: Nyawawa... show your routes.rb file please. Also your full error stacktrace

Comment: added my routes.rb file

Comment: added the stack trace 
@Ritikesh: The current_page? method is from rails itself (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html). I didn't add includes for sprockets and bootstrap yet, cause when i add "*= require bootstrap" it says it cannot find the file

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry forgot about the current_page method. Have been on rails3 for far too long. Anyway, since you're using bootstrap-sass gem, I suggest you follow their documentation correctly in setting up. Noticed that you've used require bootstrap genetically, while they suggest usage of bootstrap-sprockets to be used and bootstrap can be used for defining individual components like alert, dropdown etc. Also, if you want the bootstrap styles to be applied, please update your application.scss file as well.

Comment: @Ritikesh thanks for the advise. I thought i was using an up to date tutorial and didn't knew that the setup of my application.css was already outdated....   I changed the application.css to application.scss and added imports for bootstrap-sprockets and bootstrap. But this didnt solve the error with the links.

Comment: Hmm. Hard to find what's wrong with this one. Did you write any custom JS, and if you did, can you verify if that's working? maybe in the console?

Comment: no i didnt write any custom js yet

Answer (score 0):

i added that stuff for css and js,after that all work's fine for me.

```
    %script{src: "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        integrity: "sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS",
        crossorigin: "anonymous"}
```

also are you using -> css: `@import 'bootstrap';`

Comment: where do i have do add this?
I didn't add @import 'bootstrap' or anything comparabel to the css file

Comment: I would strongly advice against depending on third party cdns for live prod apps for your assets. And since he's using the gem, he might as well compile the assets locally.

Comment: and what about that cdn.. One time i had problem with bootstrap on heroku... Mby i did something wrong, but when i added cdn to layouts/application.html.haml that work's for me...

Comment: app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss
@import "bootstrap";                                                                                get from -> railstutorial book -  i think this is a solution for your situation.